# how to run composer update with private repo in jenkins without storing credentials in composr.json

Tags: git, jenkins, composer-php

I try to run composer within Jenkins pipeline on Ubuntu 18.04. my composer contains private repos and I use auth.json approach to store credentials. Obviously I don't want to store my credentials in VCS, so I created credential of type file in Jenkins and upload the `auth.json` file there.

I use this credential in pipeline.I copy file beside composer and run composer update.

This is the pipeline section:

```
stage('Update Project Libraries') {
        withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'composer_repo', variable: 'FILE')]) {
            dir ('src') {
                sh 'cp $FILE ./'
                sh 'composer install'
            }
        }
    }
```

and here is my auth.json file:

```
{
    "http-basic": {
        "git.myprivaterepo.com": {
            "username": "fancy",
            "password": "strong"
        }
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work:

```
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://git.myprivaterepo.com': No such  
   device or address
```

The auth.json itself works on my local machine.I can even echo auth.json body in pipeline but composer ignore it.
I also tested `sh 'use $FILE'` but nothing works.